# Extracting different data types variables from a string

Tags: c++

I'm trying to get my hands dirty with File IO here. I'm able to do basic stuff but kinda ran out of ideas here.
I want to read input from a text file. Each line of the text file follows this format: `<int> <char> <string literal> <float>`, if it doesn't it is to be ignored.

And for each line, we need to store the variables in say four data types:

```
int i;
char c;
std::string  s;
float f;
```

And print them. For the next line, they are overwritten and printed again.

**Here's my attempt:**

```
int main() {
    int i;
    char c;
    std::string  s, x;
    float f;
    ifstream in;
    in.open("Input.txt");
    if(in) {
        std::getline(in,x);
        // How do I extract i, c, s and f components from x now?
        cout << "\nInteger:" << i << ", Character: " << c << ", String: " 
             << s << ", Float: " << f << endl; 
    }
    return 0;
}
```

PS: Despite efficiency bottlenecks, please use only elementary concepts to solve this issue, not advanced stuff.

Comment: What's the question/problem?  Splitting the line (string) `x` into 4 pieces?

Comment: google sscanf it works like scanf but with strings

Comment: Yeah, 4 different data types.

Comment: @JoshuaByer: I'm very reluctant to follow anything but what's shared here on SO because most of the sites contain mistakes. I'm talking about cppreference, etc

Answer (score 3):

You can simply do:

```
while(in >> i >> c >> s >> f)
{
    cout << "\nInteger:" << i << ", Character: " << c << ", String: " 
         << s << ", Float: " << f << endl; 
}
```

---

If your values are comma-separated, you can use a `std::stringstream`/`std::getline` combination to parse the tokens (`std::getline` allows specifying a separator), like so:

```
std::stringstream ss; // from <sstream>
int field = 0; 
while (std::getline(in, ss, ','))
{
    switch (field)
    {
    case 0:
        ss >> i; 
        break;
    case 1:
        ss >> c;
        break;
    case 2: 
        ss >> s;
        break;
    case 3:
        ss >> f;
        break;
    }
    if(++field == 4)
        field = 0;
}
```

Or, you can read the whole line, remove the commas (`std::remove_if`), send the transformed line into a `stringstream`, then do `ss >> i >> c >> s >> f`.

Comment: I think when the string is reached, this will lead to a problem (unless the string can never contain white space).

Comment: @LogicStuff ahh, I though OP used `<int>` just to denote an `int`, not that the actual `<` `>` were part of the file.

Comment: @mah that's true... then it's not as simple, you need to write a parser, or use std::regex

Comment: Does this automatically ignore the lines that don't follow this format and smoothly transition to the next line without crashing?

Comment: @BloodBrother no, all lines have to have the same format, otherwise the stream end up having a `failbit` set.

Comment: Well, the practice exercise requires me to handle this case. It's supposed to ignore the divergent cases and smoothly go to the next line.

Comment: @BloodBrother you should make this clear in the question. In this case you  must use `getline` with a separator. See here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/29497543/3093378

Comment: @vsoftco: I think I mentioned it but you're right, I needed to be more clear.

Comment: @vsoftco: Can you please show how it can be applied to my problem?

Comment: I just need one good example that applies to my code so that I understand this once and for all.

Comment: @BloodBrother see the updated edit. Note that the lines have to have the same format. Otherwise, the problem becomes much more messy, you'd need a way to verify that the line is indeed in the right format, and only then parse it.